# Oh no, a Simple puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

It should be simpl<s>e</s> to find an answer to this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

> There's an image link inside the question (click the "edit" link to see it). It leads to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0kZ.png).

### Step 2

> The previous image has five characters in the top left, in a darker color than the rest of the background. Replacing the five before the `.png` in the URL with those five leads to [another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRmmI.png)

## Step 3

> The QR code in the previous image scans to `V8bzu`. This leads to *yet another* image:
>   [image]
>  The "key" needs 5 letters, and looking up those five in the table should give another image. As the question text suggests, those five letters are "simpl". (The "e" in the question is crossed out, though it's hard to see.) This leads to [the fourth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEg3o.png), which just seems to be a *very* blurry image of the word "Yes", so I assume we're done here.

Comment: Yep, that is right so far. Look at the question text precisely to find out how to continue (and the error message in the question confirms that the bsod is a correct picture)

Comment: Ok, this is correct. Oh and why are you always so ... fast? I rememeber some feature request on meta here ...

Answer (score 0):

In the

> edit screen is the following link [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0kZ.png) saying “You Got It!”

Comment: Yeah, this would be too simple ... But it's not true (at least not complete...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if all the other gibberish was just a diversion but...

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY0kZ.png was found in the question comment seen if you click on edit

After some research, I noticed that that link was something else in the original article the paragraph was taken from.

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/294807!

But that only leads to a 404 page, so it must be an old article.

I also noted that the "e" in simple has a strike in it. The "S" in the title is also wierdly a capital letter.

Comment: See my comment on El-Guest's answer...